# Haskell - cannot get next biggest prime (Couldn't match type)

Tags: haskell

I have function for finding primes and then I want to write a function which takes a number and returns first bigger prime number. Here is my approach:

```
isPrime :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
isPrime x = and $ foldl (\acc y -> (x `mod` y /= 0):acc) [] [2..round . sqrt . fromIntegral $ (x-1)]

primes = filter isPrime [2..]

getNextPrime :: (Integral a) => a -> a
getNextPrime n = head (dropWhile (<n) primes)
```

But when I try to import it to GHCI, I get this error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( a.hs, interpreted )

a.hs:35:39:
    Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Integer’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for getNextPrime :: Integral a => a -> a
          at a.hs:34:17
    Expected type: [a]
      Actual type: [Integer]
    Relevant bindings include
      n :: a (bound at a.hs:35:14)
      getNextPrime :: a -> a (bound at a.hs:35:1)
    In the second argument of ‘dropWhile’, namely ‘primes’
    In the first argument of ‘head’, namely ‘(dropWhile (< n) primes)’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

but when I try just inserting:

```
head (dropWhile (<30) primes)
```

it returns 31 as expected and its type is `Integral`.

I tried to edit types of functions or explicitly stating e.g. `n :: Integer` but it didn't help. I am sure it will be some triviality.

Thanks

Comment: You need to add a type signature for `primes`.  This would be
` `primes :: Integral a => [a] ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Simon pointed out, you need a type signature on `primes`. The following code

```
primes :: (Integral a) => [a]
primes = filter isPrime [2..]
```

compiles. GHC tries to make types without an explicit polymorphic signature (i.e., `(Integral a) => ...`) into a signature with an monomorphic type. In your case, GHC decided to "monomorphize" `[2..]` to `[Integer]`. This is known as the "[dreaded](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) [monomorphism](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.2/docs/html/users_guide/monomorphism.html) [restriction](http://lambda.jstolarek.com/2012/05/towards-understanding-haskells-monomorphism-restriction/)", for which there are myriad posts by confused SOers. So another way to make your code compile is to add the language pragma `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction`, though I strongly do not recommend this for someone learning Haskell. Adding type signatures is the way to go here.